# setMaxConns and setMaxConnsPerHost in Astyanax client

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I am using `Astyanax client` to read the data from `Cassandra database`. I have a `single cluster` with `four nodes`. I am having `replication factor of 2`. I am trying to understand what is the difference between

```
setMaxConns and setMaxConnsPerHost
```

methods in Astyanax client? I cannot find proper documentation on this.

I have a Multithreaded code which which spawn multiple threads and then create the connection to Cassandra database only once (as it is a Singleton) and then keep on reusing for other request.

Now I am trying to understand how the above two methods will play a role in read performance? And How those values should be set up?

And If I am setting those above two methods as-

```
setMaxConns(-1) and setMaxConnsPerHost(20)
```

then what does it mean? Any explanation will be of great help.

**Updated Code:-**

Below is the code, I am using to make the connection-

```
private CassandraAstyanaxConnection() {

    context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(ModelConstants.CLUSTER)
    .forKeyspace(ModelConstants.KEYSPACE)
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(20)
        .setMaxConns(-1)
        .setSeeds("host1:9160,host2:9160,host3:9160,host4:9160")
    )
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2"))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    keyspace = context.getEntity();

    emp_cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
        ModelConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY, 
        StringSerializer.get(), 
        StringSerializer.get());
}
```

If I am debugging this code, it is not even hitting the `BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl` class. I put a lot of breakpoint in the same class to see how it is using the conenctions and other default parameters. But don't know why it is not hitting that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior regarding these configuration properties might be dependent on implementation.

### BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl

`BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl` is the only implementation at the moment that honors both these properties. It behaves as follows:

Connection is borrowed from the pool on every cassandra operation (query or mutation) and returned to pool upon completion of operation.

`maxConnsPerHost` - maximum number of connections per single cassandra host.

`maxConns` - maximum number of connections in the pool.

Both these numbers must be positive, so `setMaxConns(-1)` just won't work.

On the attempt to borrow a connection from pool, the pool checks active connection number against `maxConns`. If the limit is exceeded, it waits until some connection is released. If no connection is available in specified timeout, the pool throws `PoolTimeoutException`.

If `maxConns` limit is not exceeded, the pool attempts to find a cassandra host it's aware of (specified as seed or found during discovery) that has the number of active connections below `maxConnsPerHost` and connect to it. If all hosts reached connection limit, the pool throws `NoAvailableHostsException`.

For example, let's take a client that connects to cluster of 4 nodes:

`setMaxConns(100); setMaxConnsPerHost(10)`: Effective maximum number of connections is 40 (10 connections per node, no further connection attempts will be made). `NoAvailableHostsException` will be thrown.

`setMaxConns(20); setMaxConnsPerHost(10)`: Effective maximum number of connections is 20. The connections to different hosts will be distributed uniformly, but not necessary equally.  `PoolTimeoutException` will be thrown.

Things get more complicated if nodes join or leave cluster, but general idea is the same.

### TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl & RoundRobinConnectionPoolImpl

Both `TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl` & `RoundRobinConnectionPoolImpl` ignore `maxConns` configuration property. They just select a host (depending on row token or randomly) and attempt to connect to it.

If the number of active connections to that host exceeds `maxConnsPerHost`, the pool waits until some connection is released. If no connection is available during specified timeout, another connection attempt to (potentially) another host is executed as a part of failover.

Comment: Thanks `WildFire` for the suggestion. In my case, I am using `ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl` class for the connection pooling. And I tried debugging the code by putting lot of breakpoints, and it's not even hitting the `BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl` class anywhere? Is there anything, I am missing here? I was trying to compare Pelops vs Astyanax client. So by default Pelops has 20 connections per node and maximum connections is set as -1 , so that is the reason I followed the same connection parameters in Astyanax as well. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @TechGeeky: By default Astyanax uses ConnectionPoolType.ROUND_ROBIN. See AstyanaxConfiguration.getConnectionPoolType()